# Python, having troubles with new line

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have written this code to make print out a new line after I m done providing input in one line.. so something like this

```
netM = ''

while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line: break

    netM += ''  + line
    netMs = netM.replace('.', '')
print("\n" + netMs + " = " + netMs + " or " + netM + "\n")
```

Lets say I enter,

```
Pause.now
```

it'll output..

```
Pausenow = Pausenow or Pause.now
```

But I wanna do a lot of lines at once, so it would do this..

```
Pausenow = Pausenow or Pause.now
Pausenow1 = Pausenow1 or Pause.now1
Pausenow2 = Pausenow2 or Pause.now2
```

if I entered,

```
Pause.now
Pause.now1
Pause.now2
```

and so on.

but instead it does this.

```
pauseNowpauseNow1pauseNow2 = pauseNowpauseNow1pauseNow2 or pause.Nowpause.Now1pause.Now2
```

Comment: Move your print statement inside the loop?

Comment: Then I can enter only one line of input..

Comment: How do you figure? Try it.

Comment: I tried it :P, i'm only able to input one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because raw_input() is taking input as single string.

Also you were adding entered line to newM variable for each entered input.It should be inside for loop . Define some other breakpoint instead of default 'new-line'.

Here i have used breakpoint as "" i.e empty string. Now this loop will break when you will input empty string.

```
breakpoint = ""
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if line.strip() == breakpoint:
        break
    netM = line
    netMs = netM.replace('.', '')
    print("\n" + netMs + " = " + netMs + " or " + netM + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to print the line for every iteration of loop else it will keep appending new lines to previous one just move your print statement inside the while loop 
also for your desired result don't append lines in `netM` variable

```
netM = ''

while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line: break

    netM = ''  + line
    netMs = netM.replace('.', '')
    print(netMs + " = " + netMs + " or " + netM + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should add the single string to the main string (netM) divided by `'\n'` and print the whole main string, once while loop is broken.

```
netM = ''

while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line:
            break

    netMs = line.replace('.', '')
    netM += netMs + ' = ' + netMs + ' or ' + line + '\n'

print netM
```